# how to use Order By clause on a embedded class field in apache deltaspike

Tags: deltaspike

I am trying to sort record of my employee class on the basis of updatedOn field. UpdatedOn field is in class ChangeInfo which is embedded class of employee class. I am doing this using apache deltaspike.

Example :

Criteria crtieria = findEmployees();
criteria.join(Employee_.changeInfo,where(ChangeInfo.class).orderDesc(ChangeInfo_.updatedOn));

When i use above code , i donot get a order by clause appended in final query.

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "employee")
 public class Employee 
 {
    @Id
  @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 9)
   private Long id ;
   @Column(name = "name")
   private String name;
   @Column(name = "designation")
   private String designation;
   @Embedded
   private ChangeInfo changeInfo;

}


public class ChangeInfo {

  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @Column(name = "updated_on")
  private Date updatedOn;

  @Column(name = "updatedBy")
  private String updatedBy;
}
```

Comment: Post your employee class.

Comment: @jklee added the classes .

Comment: Looks like currently Apache DeltaSpike do not support this kind of sorting . So switched back to Criteria query to get the result.